ContentUnavailableView causing entire page to be gray
I have add a List of workout that before I extracted to a subview would show the ContentUnavailableView as normal but since extracting it to a subview it now the ContentUnavailableView shows up but the entire page is now gray for some reason?
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


struct HomeView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @State private var showDuplicateButton = false
    @State private var isRotating = false
    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date.now
    
    @State private var sortOrder = SortDescriptor(\Workout.endTime, order: .reverse)
    
    @Query var workouts: [Workout]
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
        Group {
            if workouts.isEmpty {
                ContentUnavailableView {
                    Label("No workouts yet", systemImage: "dumbbell.fill")
                } description: {
                    Text("Tap the button below to get started")
                }
            actions: {
                NavigationLink {
                    AddWorkoutView()
                    
                } label : {
                    Text("Start Workout")
                        .underline()
                    
                }
                }
            }
            else {
                WorkoutListView(sort: sortOrder, selectedDate: selectedDate, showDuplicateButton: showDuplicateButton)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("\(selectedDate,  format: .dateTime.month())")
        .background(Color.gray)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button(showDuplicateButton ? "Done" : "Repeat") {
                    showDuplicateButton.toggle()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: selectedDate) ?? selectedDate
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    }
                    Text(("\(selectedDate,  format: .dateTime.month())"))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(. system(size: 18))
                    Button {
                        selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: selectedDate) ?? selectedDate
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    }
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink() {
                    AddWorkoutView()
                        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    
                } label : {
                    Image(systemName: "dumbbell.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)      // << here !!
                        .frame(width: 17, height: 17)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(isRotating ?  0 : -37))
                        .padding(5)
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            let baseAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)
            let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatCount(3)
            
            withAnimation(repeated) {
                isRotating.toggle()
            }
        }
    }

this is the subview that shows the list:
struct WorkoutListView: View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    @Query var workouts: [Workout]
    var selectedDate : Date
    
    var showDuplicateButton: Bool
        
    init(sort: SortDescriptor<Workout>, selectedDate: Date, showDuplicateButton: Bool) {
        self.showDuplicateButton = showDuplicateButton
        self.selectedDate = selectedDate
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let startOfMonth = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: selectedDate))!
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.month = 1
        components.second = -1
        let endOfMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: startOfMonth)!
        
        let predicate = #Predicate<Workout> {
            $0.endTime >= startOfMonth && $0.endTime < endOfMonth
        }
        
        _workouts = Query(filter: predicate,sort: [sort])
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Recent Workouts")) {
                ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditWorkoutView(workout: workout)
                            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    }
                    //The UI of each List Item
                label: { HStack(spacing: 19)
                    {
                        
                        if showDuplicateButton {
                            Button {
                                //the workout copy method uses the exercises copy method to copy all exercises which itself does the same for its sets
                                let newWorkout = workout.copy()
                                modelContext.insert(newWorkout)
                                //showDuplicateButton.toggle()
                                
                            }
                        label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.rectangle.on.rectangle")
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        }
                        
                        //i know this wont be nil but still best to provide a default anyway
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Text(workout.endTime.formatted(.dateTime.weekday()))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 5)
                                .padding([.bottom], 2)
                                .background(Color(red: 70/255, green: 130/255, blue: 180/255))
                                .clipShape(
                                    .rect(
                                        topLeadingRadius: 5,
                                        bottomLeadingRadius: 0,
                                        bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
                                        topTrailingRadius: 5
                                    )
                                )
                            Text(workout.endTime.formatted(.dateTime.day(.twoDigits)))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .font(.system(size: 16))
                                .padding([.top], 2)
                                .padding([.bottom], 5)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 42)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.4), lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                        
                        
                        //chatgpt why is my workout.name and exercises text not aligned?
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                            Text(workout.name)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                            
                            //The Stats
                            if let exercises =  workout.exercises {
                                Text("\(exercises.count)x Exercises")
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }

Before I put the list in a subview it was graying out but now it  contentunavailableview into the subview doesn't fix it. What could be causing this?
